# Launcher Icon Design

Tags: android

I'm more than happy coding apps.  I am, however, rubbish at icon design.  I'm sure I'm not the only one for whom this is a problem - and yet all android devs need to create a launcher icon.

Does anyone have any good tips on knocking up simple but effective launcher icons?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's what I do: I created a simple square with a shady border and some gradient fill which looks something like this (that's not mine, just something similar):

[image: http://timbunce.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/square-gradient-mask.png]

Then I go to [OpenClipArt](http://www.openclipart.org/) and get some image that fits for the application and put it on top of the square. That way I can make sure I'm not using copyrighted material while still creating some ok-looking icons.

Answer (score 5):

Try the creative commons [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to either hire an icon designer, or you can download royalty-free logo's to use as an icon, or you can try and design your own one from some inspiration here:

http://www.cutelittlefactory.com/articles/icon-inspiration-2/
http://abduzeedo.com/amazing-pictograms-and-icons

Lastly [Google](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=icon+inspiration&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&q=icon+design+inspiration&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=7db4f7af4a13aa89) it.

Use them for inspiration only, don't just blatantly copy them.

// edit:

Take a leaf from the Apple app developers, hire someone professional, it's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Google provide [Icon Design Guidlines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) document.
You can find icon style recomendations by Google there.

Hope it helps to find right icon for your app.